# Google picker not working when deployed to gae

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-drive-api, google-picker

I have developed an app in Java - Eclipse to upload images to google app engine using Google Picker API. While in development mode it works as it should, when i deploy it to Google app engine, the code stops working (as it does in development mode (stops uploading images to drive)).

I have created a Browser key, and I have that key as API key for the app. Also, in allowed referers, i have it as any referer its allowed.

I suspect that i dont have to show any code, as this isnt a coding issue. If it was, it wouldnt be working in dev mode.

Can you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error myself.

I read somewhere that an app behaviour in eclipse dev mode could be slightly different than an app behaviour deployed to google app engine.

So, i opened developer tools in chrome, and debugged the application. I found out that a function which wasnt throwing any error in dev mode, was actually throwing a null pointer exception in gae. So I debugged this, and corrected the code that was messing up the code in google app engine.

And now it works.